# Multicast address in code not getting set in DDS code

Tags: java, publish-subscribe, multicast, qos, data-distribution-service

I have the following code in my `DDS` program for `java 8` using `RTI DDS 5.2.0`

```
DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT.
    discovery.initial_peers.add("239.255.0.50");
DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT.
    discovery.initial_peers.add("4@builtin.udpv4://127.0.0.1");
DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT.
    discovery.initial_peers.add("builtin.shmem://");
DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT.
    discovery.multicast_receive_addresses.clear();
DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT.
    discovery.multicast_receive_addresses.add("239.255.0.50");
```

The setting of initial peers works correctly for the DDS code, however when I use the line to set the `multicast_receive_addresses` the address never gets set and keeps defaulting to the default multicast address.

Why is my multicast address not getting set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `set_default_participant_qos(DomainParticipantQos qos)` method to set the modified qos as new default qos. see [RTI Connext Java API](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/classcom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1domain_1_1DomainParticipantFactory.html)

Comment: Thanks! I had trouble since at first using the `DomainParticipantQos` object since I didnt know to use the set default and kept running into an error.

Comment: you're welcome. I had the same problems when I started working with RTI's wonderful Connext DDS :-) 
just keep in mind that nearly all settings in Connext are altered through first retrieving, then modifying and then writing back.

Answer (score 1):

The `multicast_recieve_address` was not set because `DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT` is just a sentinel value whose only purpose is to indicate `create_participant()` to use the default QoS--which you can set with [set_default_participant_qos](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/classcom_1_1rti_1_1dds_1_1domain_1_1DomainParticipantFactory.html#a2b61e2b4b1b1e1b0ab42b0f7ad9110ae) or [in XML](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/group__NDDSXmlConfigurationModule.html) (see also [this example](https://community.rti.com/examples/using-qos-profiles)). You should not modify `DomainParticipantFactory.PARTICIPANT_QOS_DEFAULT`.

You can also create a new `DomainParticipantQos` object, configure it, and then pass it to `create_participant()`. Examples [here](https://community.rti.com/static/documentation/connext-dds/5.2.3/doc/api/connext_dds/api_java/group__DDSParticipantExampleModule.html).